# Hashmap of hashmaps converted to json in java. When sent to jsp, i parsed it in javascript. But it is not parsed correct in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

In java

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> modFieldHash = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String, String>>();    
JSONObject modFieldJson = new JSONObject(modFieldHash); 
request.setAttribute("hash",modFieldJson);
```

In jsp,

```
JSONObject modFieldHash = (JSONObject)request.getAttribute("hash");
```

In javascript,

```
var modField = JSON.parse(<%=modFieldHash%>);
```

is my code. If hashmap is `<"chk",<"chk1","chk1">>`, then it is received as 
`{"chk","{chk1=chk1}"}` in js.
JSON.parse wont work on the second hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

For nested hash maps you will get better `JSON` rendering with the [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

Use it in `java` as follows:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> modFieldHash =
    new HashMap<String,HashMap<String, String>>();    
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
request.setAttribute("hash", gson.toJson(modFieldHash));
```

Comment: is there any way to solve this without third party libraries??